# UseCallback cache dependency from props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here some simplified component with two inputs fields and two different handlers:

```
const component = ({ data, onUpdate }) => {
  const handleChangeName = useCallback(e => {
      onUpdate({ ...data, name: e.target.value });
    }, [data],
  );

  console.log('1 here is data with updated name', data);
  const handleChangeSomeProp = useCallback(anotherProp => {
      console.log('2 here is data with empty name', data);
      onUpdate({ ...data, anotherProp: anotherProp });
    }, [data],
  );

  ... some UI components
}
```

1. First input: Updating name - everything is ok
2. Second input: When I begin typing on another field - first console log show correct data, but second console log - shows empty data without name, so it updates state to empty `data` and first field become empty again

So the question is why useCallback use old value and how to fix this.

Comment: it think it is because it is memoized and it uses reference uquality to determine wether to use new or old values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it memoized
You can solve this with `useRef`, but better to fix your hooks rerender process